# Qplot line color and legend aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to change the legend and line colors in this qplot.[image]

Here is my data

```js
   n.clusters mean.cluster mean.bucket   variable    value
1           3     21.64790    21.49858 sd.cluster 5.643380
2           5     21.63516    21.54975 sd.cluster 4.369756
3           7     21.55446    21.49889 sd.cluster 3.643280
4           9     21.59585    21.57022 sd.cluster 3.237870
5          11     21.63110    21.58452 sd.cluster 3.012060
6          13     21.55224    21.56104 sd.cluster 2.643777
7           3     21.64790    21.49858  sd.bucket 5.648886
8           5     21.63516    21.54975  sd.bucket 4.397690
9           7     21.55446    21.49889  sd.bucket 3.654752
10          9     21.59585    21.57022  sd.bucket 3.262954
11         11     21.63110    21.58452  sd.bucket 3.023834
12         13     21.55224    21.56104  sd.bucket 2.716441
```

And here is the code I used

```js
qplot(n.clusters, value, data = mu.est.summary.long,colour = variable, geom = c("point", "line"))+
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,13,2)) +
  geom_point(aes(n.clusters, value), colour = "black", size=3.5) + 
  geom_line(size=1)+
  labs(x = "Number of cluster",
       y = "Value",
       variable = "Standard deviation(sd)")
```

The legend title code line `labs(variable = "Standard deviation(sd)")` didn't work and R didn't report any error. How do I fix it?

I can color the dot on the line in black but that didn't change the legend. How do I make the legend change?

I tried to change the line color with `geom_line(colour = c("red","yellow"), size=1)` but that didn't work. How do I fix it?

Sorry for so many questions and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to fix a couple things; first, the title is called `title`, not `variable`; and second, you need to add a color scale for your lines. All together,

```
qplot(n.clusters, value, data = df, colour = variable, geom = c("point", "line"))+
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,13,2)) +
  geom_point(aes(n.clusters, value), colour = "black", size=3.5) + 
  geom_line(size=1)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'yellow')) +   # added
  labs(x = "Number of cluster",
       y = "Value",
       title = "Standard deviation(sd)")   # changed
```

produces

[image: plot with title and red and yellow lines]

Really, since you're adding on `geom_line` and `geom_point` anyway, it's simpler to use `ggplot` notation instead of `qplot`. It also makes it a little clearer how `aes` gets inherited.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(n.clusters, value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = variable), size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 13, 2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'yellow')) + 
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Number of cluster",
       y = "Value",
       title = "Standard deviation (sd)")
```

Alternately, chop out parts of `qplot` that you're overriding and move your color aesthetic to the proper place in `geom_line` (which simplifies your point color, too):

```
qplot(n.clusters, value, data = df)+
  geom_line(aes(colour = variable), size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 13, 2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'yellow')) + 
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Number of cluster",
       y = "Value",
       title = "Standard deviation(sd)")
```

Note that the order of `geom_line` and `geom_point` determines which is on top.